# Select Different Column Range Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range

So in excel vba I'm trying to select a range, but a different range every time. I have a loop going, but I was wondering how I would actually write the code to change the range. This is what it would look like for a single range.

```
Range("B7").Select
```

Is there a way to do this with integers instead of strings such as "B7"

i.e

```
Range(i).Select
```

I need it to select a single column. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `Columns(1).Select`

Comment: for single cells `Cells([row],[column])` (like `Cells(7, 2)` would be B7)

Comment: Consider reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). Using `.Select` can cause headaches in your code. What @xQbert will certainly work if you are trying to select a whole column. Say you wanted to change the range but only to loop through cells in one column, you could use something like `Range("B" & i)`

Comment: [Don't do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). @xQbert is on it, use the column directly.  You could also do `Range("B7").EntireColumn` or with a variable, `Dim myCol as Long // myCol = Range("B7").Column`  But you don't "really" want to select the column, but *do* something with that column. Check out the Thread I linked to, it will save you many headaches and help your code run faster.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you only have to selct one Cell:

```
Cells(y, x)
```

But because you have to select more:

```
Dim testRange As Range

   Set testRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(100, 1))

   testRange.Select 'Optional
   testRange = "If you read this, you are awsome!"
```

Including that you want a loop:

```
Dim testRange As Range
Dim x as Integer

  For x = 1 To n 'n = whatever you want
     Set testRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, x), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(100, x))

     testRange.Select 'Optional
     testRange = "If you read this, you are even more awesome!" 'Fills 100x100 Cells with this text
  Next x
```

I hope that's helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the cell is relative to the starting row you could use offset to do something like this:

```
dim rng as Range
dim i as integer
set rng = range("B7")
for i=0 to 10
   rng.offset(0,i).select
next i
```

Look up offset to learn how to modify this to suit your needs